# Safari Not Clearing HTML5 Videos from Cache

Tags: macos, caching, video, safari, html5-video

In Safari (Version 8.0 (10600.1.25.1)) on OS X (10.10.1), Safari is not emptying caches correctly. I have a website that contains two HTML5 videos (MP4/WEBM). However, I have recently changed these videos. On every other browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer, etc.), the correct video plays. Even if I go to the direct link in the URL bar in Safari (both MP4 and WebM), the old videos show.

I have emptied the cache, I have even ticked "Disable Cache" and it sill will not play the correct video.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and clear your history. You may need to update you browser as well.

Comment: This is the latest version of Safari, and it doesn't matter how much I clear my cache, history or whatever. It still uses the old video, somehow.